# Django returning 500 on POST request

Tags: javascript, django

So, I have this simple contact form, which Django handles by sending e-mails to me and to the person who contacted us. I've written an AJAX funcion to handle it. The only thing is that, no matter what I try, I keep getting an 500 status.

My Django (1.11) code:

```
def contato(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        message = request.POST['message']
        newmessage = "Mensagem recebida de {}.\nTelefone: {}\ne-mail {}\n {}".format(name, phone, email, message)
        send_mail(
            'Nova mensagem pelo site',
            newmessage,
            'PLACEHOLDER@EMAIL',
            ['PLACEHOLDER@EMAIL'],
            fail_silently=False
        )
        send_mail(
            'Recebemos sua mensagem!',
            'Olá, {}!\nRecebemos sua mensagem e entraremos em contato em breve.'.format(name),
            'PLACEHOLDER@EMAIL',
            [email],
            fail_silently=False
        )
        return HttpResponse()
```

And here's my AJAX request:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let dadoscontato = {
        name: name.value,
        email: email.value,
        phone: phone.value,
        message: message.value,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
    };

    fetch('/contato/', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dadoscontato),
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response){
        alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
    });
});
```

Comment: An HTTP 500 is a generic "Internal Server Error". Do you have logging in Django? Have you tried debugging that block of Django code to see the actual error?

Comment: Managed to run on a development server. this is what I got:
```
  File "D:\Documentos\Project\perolavenus\pearlphotography\views.py", line 24, in contato
    name = request.POST['name']
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'name'"
[01/Dec/2019 00:15:56] "POST /contato/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71944
```

Comment: Hmm. Does Django expect the body to be a string? Currently you're assigning `body: JSON.stringify(dadoscontato)`. I would think that's posting a single string to the server rather than a JSON object. Try sending `dadoscontato` without `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Now I have a new error: my request only gets "None" values and my javascript raises the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: Got it. I had to run a .decode() while loading the response. Everything works fine now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this question as solved:

I had to run a `.decode()` while loading the response. Everything works fine now.